# Issues running CAMEL JAR file built in windows using Eclipse when run in Linux command line using JAVA or MVN command

Tags: jar, apache-camel

```
I have built a Camel project in Eclipse with Maven dependencies.
```

It ran successfully and also Built the Jar file and ran it from the command prompt 
which is running as required. But when I moved the JAR file onto to our Linux machine 
which is like a Job Manager server and when I try to run the JAR file as below 
I am getting the below error message.

```
When I try to run with the below command

$ java –jar mycamelproject

I am getting the below error, but I do have the below mentioned dependency in the Dependency-Jars folder.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/c
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.support
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 6 more
Then I tried running with the below command.

$ mvn -X exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=mycamelpackage.mycamelmainclass         

I am getting a series of the below errors such as below

    [DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in local (/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository)

[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml, already updated during this session.

[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from
```

http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): proxy.host.net

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'exec' in the current project
```

and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
 available from the repositories

Answer (score 0):

How should `java –jar mycamelproject` work if no classpath is set? And `mycamelproject` should be a JAR file anyway (and if it is, you should add the `*.jar` extension).

Beside that, I guess your local Maven repository may be corrupt. That's usually the reason why you see the `resolution will not be reattempted` error message. The easiest way to fix this is to remove the corrupt directories and start Maven again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply peter..got it sorted..as u mentioned i have been using the .jar in the command line while executing....The actual problem was that the dependency-jar were not being picked when I run the .jar file. I have copied the dependency-jars folder into the same folder where the executable jar is there and ran it and it solved the issue....